# npm install issues - react native project - mac

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm

I am trying to clone a remote react-native project but I am getting errors when running the npm install command to download all the dependencies in the package.json folder.

I am in the same root directory where the package.json file is.
This is what I get when running npm install:

[image: first error]

when I try doing npm install --force or npm install --legacy-deps I get:

[image: second error]

I've tried uninstalling node reinstalling to the LTS and current version.
This is the process I followed when trying to install the dependencies:

- clone remote repo
- npm init
- npm install

I am not quite sure what else to do any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Make sure that you are in the right directory

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get in project directory then install the node packages

```
cd <ProjectName> 
npm install
```